# Why do we need to update applications on our computer even when they work fine?

Tags: updates

If the update reminder says that we need to update an application, and we don't seem to have a problem with it, what is the problem if we skip the update?

Comment: For example, there could be security issues, especially for things like web browsers. Updates sometimes introduce new features, too.

Comment: Whether you want to update or not is ultimately your choice. Like @JonasCz said, some of the updates may be security updates, in which case you should get them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be problems that are not apparent to you, or new features that are being added.

For example, web browsers are often updated with security patches and new features. More specifically, the most recent update of Chrome (`google-chrome-stable`), had a [large number of security fixes](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.ca/2016/05/stable-channel-update_25.html). A prior update had an overhaul of the appearance (which I would consider a new feature).